# Concat (Merge) Asymmetrical Data frame Table in Python Pandas to Create Relationship Table

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

So I have two tables, Table1 and Table2

Table1:

| Key1 | Key2 |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 |

Table2:

| Key3 | Key4 | Key5 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | D1 | E1 |
| C2 | D2 | E2 |
| C3 | D3 | E3 |
| ... | ... | ... |

And I want to combine both makings Table 3

| Key2 | Key4 |
| --- | --- |
| B1 | D1 |
| B1 | D2 |
| B1 | D3 |
| B1 | ... |

is there a function in pandas that would make this possible

Thanks.

Update:
Using Andrej Kesely's solution below.

code:

```
#create relationship tables from dataframes above
userinforel = pd.merge(computerlist,userinfo , how="cross")[["Name","UserInfo.UserName"]] #works
monitorlistrel = pd.merge(computerlist,monitorlist , how="cross")[["Name","SerialNumber"]] #does not work
```

output:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['Name', 'SerialNumber'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
p:\Tech Support\LoginReport\LoginReport-To-SQL\LoginReport-to-SQL.py in <module>
    127 
    128 if __name__ == "__main__":
--> 129     main()

p:\Tech Support\LoginReport\LoginReport-To-SQL\LoginReport-to-SQL.py in main()
    117             json_to_sql(file.path) """
    118 
--> 119     json_to_sql('SK82-081AL101-20210903.0853.json') #loginreport v2
    120     #json_to_sql('SK82-081AL026-20210803.0849.json') #loginreport v1
    121 

p:\Tech Support\LoginReport\LoginReport-To-SQL\LoginReport-to-SQL.py in json_to_sql(JSONFILE)
     80         #create relationship tables from dataframes above
     81         userinforel = pd.merge(computerlist,userinfo , how="cross")[["Name","UserInfo.UserName"]]
---> 82         monitorlistrel = pd.merge(computerlist,monitorlist , how="cross")[["Name","SerialNumber"]]
     83         #printerlistrel = pd.merge(computerlist,printerlist , how="cross")[["Name","ID"]]
     84         #programlistrel = pd.merge(computerlist,programlist , how="cross")[["Name","IDName"]]

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3459             if is_iterator(key):
   3460                 key = list(key)
-> 3461             indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1)[1]
   3462 
   3463         # take() does not accept boolean indexers

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _get_listlike_indexer(self, key, axis)
   1312             keyarr, indexer, new_indexer = ax._reindex_non_unique(keyarr)
   1313 
-> 1314         self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer, axis)
   1315 
   1316         if needs_i8_conversion(ax.dtype) or isinstance(

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis)
   1372                 if use_interval_msg:
   1373                     key = list(key)
-> 1374                 raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
   1375 
   1376             not_found = list(ensure_index(key)[missing_mask.nonzero()[0]].unique())

KeyError: "None of [Index(['Name', 'SerialNumber'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

Update 2:
Turns out there were similar column name as Andrej Kesely's mentioned below, using suffix to fix the issue.

```
#create relationship tables from dataframes above
userinforel = pd.merge(computerlist,userinfo, how="cross")[["Name","UserInfo.UserName"]] #works
monitorlistrel = pd.merge(computerlist,monitorlist, how="cross")[["Name_x","SerialNumber_y"]] #works
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try cross-merge:

```py
df_out = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="cross")[["Key2", "Key4"]]
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
  Key2 Key4
0   B1   D1
1   B1   D2
2   B1   D3
```

Comment: Hi, this worked in one of the tables that only have one row, but when I did the same to the other table with multiple rows it shows an error message saying:

KeyError: "None of [Index(['Name', 'SerialNumber'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: @CrisantoIII Are there common column names in `df1`, `df2`? If yes, you need to add suffix `_x` or `_y` accordingly.

Comment: @CrisantoIII For example `["Name_x","SerialNumber_y"]` but is hard to tell without seeing your real data.